# build vim 64bit on windows 7

Tags: vim, 64-bit, python

i am trying to build 64bit vim on win7 64bit with visual studio 2008.
My python34 is 64bit version.

Below is what i did.

1. hg to get the vim source.
2. set `VCDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC"`
3. call `%VCDIR%\bin\amd64\vcvarsamd64.bat`
4. `%VCDIR%\bin\nmake -f Make_mvc.mak CPU=AMD64 GUI=yes OLE=yes PYTHON3=C:\Python34 DYNAMIC_PYTHON3=yes PYTHON3_VER=34 CSCOPE=yes FEATURES=HUGE ARABIC=no FARSI=no OPTIMIZE=SPEED`

but when the build fails with

```
link /RELEASE /nologo /subsystem:windows /LTCG:STATUS -out:gvim.exe .\ObjGOHAMD64\blowfish.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\buffer.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\charset.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\diff.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\digraph.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\edit.obj
  .\ObjGOHAMD64\eval.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\ex_cmds.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\ex_cmds2.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\ex_docmd.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\ex_eval.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\ex_getln.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\fileio.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\fold.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\getchar.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\hardcopy.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\hashtab.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\main.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\mark.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\mbyte.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\memfile.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\memline.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\menu.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\message.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\misc1.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\misc2.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\move.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\normal.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\ops.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\option.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\os_mswin.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\winclip.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\os_win32.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\pathdef.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\popupmnu.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\quickfix.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\regexp.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\screen.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\search.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\sha256.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\spell.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\syntax.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\tag.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\term.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\ui.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\undo.obj
  .\ObjGOHAMD64\window.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\vim.res .\ObjGOHAMD64\gui.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\gui_beval.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\gui_w32.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64\os_w32exe.obj .\ObjGOHAMD64\if_ole.obj      .\ObjGOHAMD64\if_python3.obj     .\ObjGOHAMD64/if_cscope.obj .\ObjGOHAMD64/netbeans.obj  .\ObjGOHAMD64/xpm_w32.obj .\ObjGOHAMD64\version.obj oldnames.lib kernel32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib gdi32.lib  comdlg32.lib ole32.lib uuid.lib /machine:AMD64 /nodefaultlib gdi32.lib version.lib   winspool.lib comctl32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib  /machine:AMD64 /nodefaultlib libcmt.lib oleaut32.lib  user32.lib       /nodefaultlib:python34.lib    WSock32.lib xpm\x64\lib\libXpm.lib /PDB:gvim.pdb -debug
fatal error C1905: Front end and back end not compatible (must target same processor).
LINK : fatal error LNK1257: code generation failed
```

you can see that `link.exe` still tries to link some 32-bit libraries.

Can you tell me how I can solve this?

### Update:

my python tells me that:
Python 3.4.0 (v3.4.0:04f714765c13, Mar 16 2014, 19:25:23) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32

I don't know Why the 64bit python has *win32* at the end. or does someone knows where to get a 64bit python on win64?

Comment: A couple things come to mind, from past build failures on my machine: 1) are you linking against 64-bit Python? 2) are you doing this from a clean directory, or have you built 32-bit versions from here before?

Comment: @Ben, for python issue, see my update above. and I am sure this is clean work space and i never did 32-bit compilation before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through Make_mvc.bat in my work space again and taking Ben's advice, I finally successfully compiled my vim 64-bit.

The reason that I failed is what Ben's mentioned, the previous compilation remaining.

If you encountered the same issue again, please check whether you have such folders as "ObjGOHAMD64".
You can delete it manually for a clean build.